# Importing large sql file to local server with PHPmyAdmin

Tags: php, sql, import, mamp

I'm trying to import a large sql file to my localhost.

When I attempt the import I get the following error

"No data was received to import. Either no file name was submitted, or the file size exceeded the maximum size permitted by your PHP configuration. "

Is their another way I can import the sql file? Possibly form the terminal?(on a Mac)

Comment: have you tried using mysql directly? or setting set_time_limit(0) in php?

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with either of those methods.

Comment: i was stating that using mysql ( the CLI) in order to import your file as in [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqlimport.html) or unsetting the timelimit for the execution of your script in php (set_time_limit does this). But apparently your problem was the size of the import, that is why you marked that answer as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit php.ini, set upload_max_filesize to greater than the size of the file you are uploading.